# High volume queryable and traversable data structure

Tags: java, database, data-structures, graph, jo4neo

I'm building an application and need a data structure of interconnected objects that can be queried and traversed.  The connections between objects can be arbitrary and not necessarily known before hand.  I need this data structure to be queryable (what usual SQL provides) and also traversable (what new graph database like neo4j provide).  I'm trying to get something that does both and works with very large data sets efficiently.  Let's call this data structure dao.  I would need the following primitive methods:

```
// dealing with the objects
dao.save(s);
Something s = dao.load(Something.class, 5);
dao.update(s);
dao.delete(s);

// dealing with the relations
dao.relate(s, t);
dao.unrelate(s, t);

// the tricky methods
dao.querier(Something.class).filter(...).sort(...).values();
dao.traverser(Something.class).start(s).path(...).filter(...).sort(...).values();
```

The **filter** would be something like the sql where clause, the **sort** would be something like the sql order clause, the **start** would be the starting node for the traversal, and the **path** would define things like BFS and DFS traversing as well as when to stop searching.

I've tried to model this as vertices with an adjacency list but there must be a better way.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org) would be a good option. Beside the raw usage from Java, [Jo4neo](http://code.google.com/p/jo4neo/) provides annotation-based persistence for your object model onto the graph. For querying, you either can use the Neo4j high speed Java [Traversers](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/Traverser.html), or use things like the [JRuby Wrapper](http://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j) that does provide very convenient abstractions for queries from JRuby. Also, [Gremlin](http://wiki.github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/) is specialized on deep graph traversals, but not yet optimized for speed.

Answer (score 0):

maybe using the [sparql](http://components.neo4j.org/sparql-engine-neo/apidocs/index.html) query engine for neo4j?